# Why am I receiving "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on a defined array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I defined, initialized(TWICE) my array, yet i am getting "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at runtime.

I already tried to check if the array was defined as you can see in my code, still angular is just trolling me.
I already tried all solutions like changing the sintax to "filesToUpload && filesToUpload?.length > 0" or any possible combination, however Angular is just not working properly imo.

component.html file

```
<ng-container *ngIf="undefined !== filesToUpload && filesToUpload.length > 0">
  <button (click)='uploadImages()' 
           class="btn btn-success" 
           type="button">
          <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>Upload
  </button>

  <button (click)='cancelUpdate()' 
          class="btn btn-danger" 
          type="button">Cancel</button>
</ng-container>
```

This is my component.ts file

```
export class ImageGalleryUploadComponent implements OnInit 
{
  filesToUpload: File[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filesToUpload = []
  }
}
```

is this an angular bug? or has something to do with component lifecycle?

Comment: Just replace *ngIf="filesToUpload && filesToUpload.length > 0" . It will handle null and undefined both.

Comment: already tried, but I am still receiving this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, somewhere you are assigning `undefined` to your Array object.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="filesToUpload && filesToUpload != 'undefined' && filesToUpload.length > 0">
```

Though it's not a good practice, just try it once and if confirmed then cross-check in your code.

Comment: I don't know why this is different but it worked... WHY?! Could you explain, please? Why is not a good practice?

Comment: @brk yes, we already checking variable it's not required to put ? there. I will edit my answer

Comment: I think checking `undefined` in a string is not a good idea. I am working on it as same issue occurred to me, once get the clarity. I will let you know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way using safe navigation operator and it will handle null and lentgh of files in one go,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="filesToUpload && filesToUpload?.length > 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it once like:

```
export class ImageGalleryUploadComponent implements OnInit 
{
  filesToUpload: File[] = [];
}
```

I have faced this issue as well. Removing the re-initialisation from `ngOnInit` should fix the issue. And don't worry every time the component is initialised it will be set to `[]`.

Comment: I also tried this haha I swear I already tried all the logic solutions

Comment: Ok, can you create a function that returns Boolean and move this logic to the component.ts file ?